# How to optimally merge two big dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one with more than 60,000,000 rows and another with 500,000 rows. I want to merge these two dataframes based on a mulitiindex. my IDE is jupyter, and the memory of my PC is 16G, CPU is 2.3GHz, 64bits.

How to merge it optimally? 
I have some requirements. I need to get the overlapping part.
Also, I wonder if there is some deeper way to optimize it, like using Cpython or something? I don't know exactly cause I just read it here [enhancing performance](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

The df A is like:

```
                    time                 brand
user_id  sku_id   
27630    37957  2016-02-01 07:43:14       8
489      37957  2016-02-01 07:43:04       8
489      37957  2016-02-01 07:43:02       8
661      21546  2016-02-01 07:43:02       6
……
```

The df B is like:

```
                   time                 brand
user_id  sku_id   
27630    37957  2016-02-01 07:43:14       8
489      37957  2016-02-01 07:43:04       8
764      37957  2016-02-01 07:43:02       8
667      2156   2016-02-01 07:43:02       3
……
```

Comment: Twice you've linked to a source that apparently shows how this can be optimised with Cython but I don't see the reference in the links. Also, Cython is generally to try and optimise an extension to the main library, not enforced to use the base functionality most efficiently. If a generic join could be done more efficiently, why wouldn't that be the base implementation?

Comment: @roganjosh I didn't mean Cython is the specific way. I just want know different kinds of optimal methods not just within Pandas. By the way, I tried join, merge, but it didn't work well. I don't know how long 100millions-level data merge take is normal, but in my PC, it takes more than 10minutes but still be unfinished.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Index.intersection](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) in this case:

**Solution:**

```
In [159]: A.loc[A.index.intersection(B.index)]
Out[159]:
                               time  brand
user_id sku_id
489     37957   2016-02-01 07:43:04      8
        37957   2016-02-01 07:43:02      8
27630   37957   2016-02-01 07:43:14      8
```

[Pandas documentation: Merge, join, and concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: Do you have more efficient way? cause I am trying to use join, but  6 minutes passed, it is still unfinished.

Comment: @Husy, in order to answer that question we need to see a __reproducible__ sample data sets. Depending on your data sets and your goals you can use `join`, `merge`, `concat`, `map`. If you don't want to provide a reproducible data sets - you can play with those four methods and choose the one which fits the best for your data and needs...

Comment: I tried. It works. thank you. Why it is faster than join? Could you please show me some materials?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) operation?

df=df1.merge(df2,how='outer',on='your required column or index')

`Parameters:`

how : {‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’}, default ‘inner’

left: use only keys from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join; preserve key order

right: use only keys from right frame, similar to a SQL right outer join; preserve key order

outer: use union of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL full outer join; sort keys lexicographically

inner: use intersection of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL inner join; preserve the order of the left keys

on : label or list:-Field names to join on. Must be found in both DataFrames. If on is None and not merging on indexes, then it merges on the intersection of the columns by default.

Comment: of course I have tried. I wonder if there is some deeper way to optimize it, like using Cpython or something? I don't know cause I just read it here [enhancing performance](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)